# XDE crashes when using Location Services

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8

Hey guys wondering if anyone can shed some light on my situation.

I'm coding an app which makes use of location services to access Yelp and find businesses nearby. I'm running into an issue when I attempt to debug on the XDE.exe simulator.

Not sure how to fix it and I've attempted to make use of my GoogleFu but to no avail.

```
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Your App does not have permission to access location data. Make sure you have defined ID_CAP_LOCATION in the application manifest and that on your phone, you have turned on location by checking Settings > Location.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did you check the manifest as the error message says? Without that capability your app will crash when it tries to make location calls.

Comment: I have indeed put that into the app manifest now however when I run the app it just sits there with the loading bars just going and going. I've attempted to insert a break point and find out where it's failing and I've put a few in but it doesn't seem to make it even to the Main Page constructor... quite strange. I need to investigate more.